# Vue.js: Cannot trigger ready of a component when only a param of route change

Tags: javascript, mvvm, ecmascript-6, vue-router, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js 1.0 with vue-router.

I have a component `UserList.vue`:

```
<template>
  <a v-link="{name: "user_list", params: {cat: 'admin'}}">admin</a>
  <a v-link="{name: "user_list", params: {cat: 'normal'}}">normal</a>
</template>

<script>
  export default = {
    methods: {
      reload() {
        // Do the data reloading.
      },
    },
    ready() {
      console.log(this.$route.params);
      reload();
    },
  };
</script>
```

I have configured the router item to be:

```
router.map({
  '/home': {
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
  },
  '/user/:cat': {
    name: 'user_list',
    component: UserList,
  },
});
```

So, when I switch to `/user/admin` from the `Home.vue` component, the `ready()` function of `UserList.vue` is triggered.

But when I switch between `/user/admin` and `/user/normal`, the `ready()` function is not triggered.

But I want to load the data then, How to make a stable way to trigger the `ready()` function?

Comment: its because views are being reused by default. Set `canReuse` to false will help you with that.

Comment: @MathewJibin, sound's a good solution, but how? I didn't found the option in the manual.

Comment: Posted an answer since its slightly large for a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer applies to router version 0.7 with Vuejs version 1.x

You need to set the `canReuse` to `false` to always trigger the `ready` hook because as the documentation states, it is not triggered on subsequent uses when view is reused which is the default setting.

```
<script>
  export default = {
    route:{
     canReuse:false //or a function returning boolean
    }
    methods: {
      reload() {
        // Do the data reloading.
      },
    },
    ready() {
      console.log(this.$route.params);
      reload();
    },
  };
</script>
```

The [canReuse documentation](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/1.0/docs/en/pipeline/can-reuse.md) has a few more details. This setting is no more available in newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

After a long period to try, I found it is hard to trigger the `ready()` function.

But we can change the redirection to a method rather than v-link:

```
<template>
  <a @click="setCat('admin')">admin</a>
  <a @click="setCat('normal')">normal</a>
</template>
```

And then manually call the `reload()` function in the method:

```
export default {
  // ...
  methods: {
    setCat(cat) {
      this.$route.params.cat = cat;
      this.reload();
      this.$router.go({name: 'user_list', params: {cat}});
    }
  }
}
```